# Strange behavior of UITableViewController in iOS12 notch models, when the language setting of iPhone is Japanese or Chinese

Tags: uitableview, rotation, xcode10, ios12, iphone-xs

This problem occurs depending on the language setting of iPhone.
I was able to confirm this problem in Japanese and Chinese.
In English etc. this problem does not occur.

I have created a simple project that installing UINavigationController on the storyboard, using Xcode10. rootViewController is the default UITableViewController.
I have not changed anything nearly anything on the storyboard.
I use an array of Strings 1 to 5 as datasource of UITableView.

If I build and rotate this on iOS12, UITableView will be plus offset top or it will be under NavigationBar.
This problem does not occur in iOS11. Also, no problems will occur in models without notch.
This problem occurs only with notched models of iOS12. (iPhone X, XS, XS Max, Xr)

Does anyone know the cause of this strange problem?
Thank you.

[image: strange plus offset of top]

[image: under NavigationBar]

I uploaded my project to GitHub. Could you confirm it?

[yaslam2222/SimpleTableViewController](https://github.com/yaslam2222/SimpleTableViewController)

Comment: What is table view’s `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`?

Comment: Also please show code. Are you reloading the table view?

Comment: @matt
Since contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior has not set a value arbitrarily, it is default automatic.  
Also, setting this other value to contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior does not fix this problem. I uploaded my project to GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the github project! I can't reproduce any problem with it.

Comment: @matt Thank you for confirmation. 
In my environment this problem will always be reproduced.
Did you rotate the device several times after launching the application?
Have you confirmed with models with notch of iOS12? (iPhone X, XS, XS Max, XR)

Comment: @matt I found a strange cause!!
This problem occurs depending on the language setting of iPhone.
I was able to confirm this problem in Japanese and Chinese.
In English etc this problem does not occur.
Is this a bug in iOS12?

Comment: Yes!!!! I can confirm this behavior with Chinese language and system on an iOS 12 iPhone X simulator — but with an iOS 11 iPhone X simulator, there's no problem. You can download the iOS 11 simulator SDK and try it for yourself.

Comment: By the way, to experiment, you don't need to change the Settings on the simulator; just use the pop-up menus in the Scheme (Run -> Options, Application Language and Application Region).

Comment: @matt On the simulator, it was confirmed just by changing the language setting of the scheme. It is very convenient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've found a bug! (As you have rightly explained, this happens only on an X device, only in iOS 12, and only in a Chinese or Japanese environment.)

Here is a workaround — not very satisfactory, but at least it *is* a workaround:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I will consider using edgesForExtendedLayout as temporary solution.

Comment: It's not much but it does work. You should report this as a bug to Apple!

Comment: Yes, I will report this bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this bug to Apple. Apple responded that it shall be fixed on iOS 12.1.
I installed Xcode 10.1 beta 2 and confirmed this bug on iOS 12.1 simulator.
I confirmed that this bug has been fixed on iOS 12.1 (simulator).
Thank you.

[image]
[image]